# Extracting cell contents based on the string within the cell using dictionaries

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am quite new to VBA and was looking through stackoverflow. I found a neat VBA macro that utilizes Dictionaries and seemed like it could be applied to my problem also. However, after editing the macro I can't seem to make it work like I mean to.

My data is as follows: In column A I have Review numbers, Review topics and Analysis numbers. These follow a structure where Review number is 1st, then 2 rows later there is Review topic and under Review topic can be multiple Analysis numbers but the 1st one is 2 rows below the Review topic. In column B there are details about the reviewed item. I am interested in 3 different ones(height, weight and price). There is sometimes extra details here which is why I use string-matching (InStr). Sometimes there are less details. In general the data does not have a specific enough form to rely on the amount of rows between specific groups of data.

Data looks generally like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaqWR.jpg

The goal is to move extract the contents of the cells containing Review number, Review topic, Analysis number, Height, Weight and Price. These should be in separate cells on the same row. In case of multiple analysis, the following analysis should be below the row containing the 1st analysis and height, weight and price following this like before. Review number and topic dont need to be duplicated.

In the code I use dictionaries and a whole lotta ElseIfs. As I said, this is largely taken from another post. It works fine if I try to find the 1st analysis detail but when I try to find all 3 it stops working altogether giving me error 424 object required on the 2 last ElseIfs in the 1st loop. Moreover, the part that mostly works (finding the detailA which is height) only works if the searched string is found on the cell one row below the current row. In other words, it only works if the height/detailA is on row i+1

```
Sub FindData()

    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim reportsheet As Worksheet

    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim SearchString2 As String

    Dim i As Integer

    Set datasheet = Sheet1
    Set reportsheet = Sheet2

    Dim chNum As String
    Dim chSub As String
    Dim analysisNum As String
    Dim detailA As String
    Dim detailB As String
    Dim detailC As String
    Dim ReviewCollection As New Dictionary

    Dim dictKey1 As Variant
    Dim dictKey2 As Variant
    Dim dictKey3 As Variant
    Dim dictKey4 As Variant
    Dim dictKey5 As Variant
    Dim dictKey6 As Variant

    reportsheet.Range("A1:H200").ClearContents
    finalrow = datasheet.Cells(datasheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To finalrow
        SearchString = datasheet.Range("A" & i)
        SearchString2 = datasheet.Range("B" & i)

        If InStr(1, SearchString, "Review number") Then
            chNum = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)
            ReviewCollection.Add chNum, New Dictionary 'For review numbers
        ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString, "Review topic") Then
            chSub = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)
            ReviewCollection.Item(chNum).Add chSub, New Dictionary 'For review topics
        ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString, "Analysis number") Then
            analysisNum = datasheet.Cells(i, 1)
            ReviewCollection.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Add analysisNum, New Dictionary 'For Analysis numbers
        ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString2, "Height") Then
            detailA = datasheet.Cells(i, 2)
            ReviewCollection.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(analysisNum).Add detailA, New Dictionary 'For Analysis detail #1
        'ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString2, "Weight") Then
        '    detailB = datasheet.Cells(i, 2)
        '    ReviewCollection.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(analysisNum).Item(detailA).Add detailB, New Dictionary 'For Analysis detail #2
        'ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString2, "Price") Then
        '    detailA = datasheet.Cells(i, 2)
        '    ReviewCollection.Item(chNum).Item(chSub).Item(analysisNum).Item(detailA).Item(detailB).Add detailC, New Dictionary 'For Analysis detail #3
        End If
    Next i

'Loop to print out the dictionary
    i = 1
    For Each dictKey1 In ReviewCollection.Keys
        reportsheet.Cells(i, 1) = dictKey1 'Review number

        If ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Count > 0 Then
            For Each dictKey2 In ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Keys
                reportsheet.Cells(i, 2) = dictKey2 'Review topic

                If ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Count > 0 Then
                    For Each dictKey3 In ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Keys 'Report Number
                        reportsheet.Cells(i, 3) = dictKey3
                        If ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Item(dictKey3).Count > 0 Then
                            For Each dictKey4 In ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Item(dictKey3).Keys 'Analysis detail #1
                                reportsheet.Cells(i, 4) = dictKey4
                                'START of the printing for the problematic area
                                If ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Item(dictKey3).Item(dictKey4).Count > 0 Then
                                    For Each dictKey5 In ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Item(dictKey3).Item(dictKey4).Keys 'Analysis detail #2
                                    reportsheet.Cells(i, 5) = dictKey5
                                        If ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Item(dictKey3).Item(dictKey4).Item(dictKey5).Count > 0 Then
                                            For Each dictKey6 In ReviewCollection.Item(dictKey1).Item(dictKey2).Item(dictKey3).Item(dictKey4).Item(dictKey5).Keys 'Analysis detail #3
                                                reportsheet.Cells(i, 6) = dictKey6
                                            Next dictKey6
                                        Else
                                            i = i + 1 'no reports, so moves down to prevent overwriting change number
                                        End If
                                    Next dictKey5
                                Else
                                    i = i + 1 'no reports, so moves down to prevent overwriting change number
                                End If
                                'END of the problematic area
                            Next dictKey4
                        Else
                            i = i + 1 'no reports, so moves down to prevent overwriting change number
                        End If
                    Next dictKey3
                Else
                    i = i + 1 'no reports, so moves down to prevent overwriting change number
                End If
            Next dictKey2
        Else
            i = i + 1 'no change subject, so moves down to prevent overwriting change number
        End If
    Next dictKey1
End Sub
```

I am also open to any other improvements. My logic seems very heavy but I couldn't get it working even to this degree with any of the other ways (tried using more loops and less if-structures).

I plan on trimming the contents of the cells to only include the numbers but this is a worry for the future. I already have made working excel formulas for this.

Comment: To avoid "object required" check for "Is Not Nothing". Looks to me you could drop all the i = i + 1 in the elses and just increment i at the end of your last endif.